# Asking about writing techniques

Tags: creative-writing

Could you please help me..I have ideas of writings and stories, but..when I come to start writing, I can't find what I need to write the plot and that's leads me to think about giving up

Comment: Does [this](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/1781/how-do-i-construct-a-plot-out-of-my-many-setting-character-details) help?

Comment: https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/50892/how-can-i-begin-writing-a-short-story

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A useful classification for ideas is their level of detail. Depending on which class best describes your ideas, some methods to formulate a story might come more naturally to you than others.

On one end of the spectrum exist 'big picture' ideas that encompass your entire story but only in broad strokes. If you can prepend "the story is about" to the idea, it probably is part of this class. A few concrete examples:

- A man who searches for his wife in an abandoned holiday town after receiving a letter, three years after her death
- A young girl who sues her parents for forcing her to donate a kidney to her dying sister
- A coke-snorting hacker who travels into outer space to stop two AIs from merging and becoming sentient

'Big picture' ideas can be turned into full stories by adding layers of detail. Take your one-sentence summary and expand it into a hundred words. Paint broad strokes; now's not the time to describe the protagonist's difficult childhood. Also, don't be afraid to rewrite those hundred words until you have something you like.

The next stage is to divide your story into three acts, and from there, to start work on an outline. This technique is called the [snowflake method](https://www.advancedfictionwriting.com/articles/snowflake-method/), and I encourage you to read the linked article because it goes into much deeper detail.

On the other end of the spectrum exist fragmented ideas. Perhaps for characters, items, locations, half the set-up for a scene that looks cool in your head. Each a puzzle piece, though not all necessarily from the same set. Examples:

- Protagonist befriends a talking cat (character)
- Temple on the moon built by ancient Egyptians (location)
- Character goes through experimental chemotherapy and becomes violently ill (scene)

If you have a large number of these ideas, your job is to find out how they piece together, if at all. Write each idea on a Post-It. Rearrange your Post-Its in groups that make the most sense to you. See if a possible narrative begins to form. For instance, using bullet points #1 and #2:

> On a school trip to the British Museum, Lydia meets a talking black cat who claims to be a reincarnation of the Egyptian goddess Bastet. Bastet convinces her to board a NASA rocket, and they travel to the moon to reclaim her lost temple.

The emerging narrative need not and will not be perfect. You'll have many questions. Why does Bastet want her temple back? Why is Lydia the only person who can help? How does an eleven-year-old travel from Britain to the US, alone, sneak onto a rocket ship unseen, and survive the massive g-forces involved in lift-off? Write all questions down in a notebook and answer them. When answering one question creates another, answer it as well until none remain. What remains is a document with all the facts you need to write an outline.

Comment: Thanks so much.. but I don't know why while I'm writing, I think that this gonna be useless and thoughts about giving up start overwhelming me. Is this a lack of confidence or maybe because it's the first time I write ?

Comment: @NourFourti That voice is called your 'inner editor' and it is both your best friend and worst enemy. The editor insists you write well as a self-defense mechanism against criticism both real and imagined. Problem is, the editor is a little too overprotective and will prevent you from writing so much as a single word if you don't put it on a leash. While writing the first draft, ignore whatever the voice says. Your first draft will be trash, but every author faces this problem. The editing comes later.

Comment: @NourFourti If you use the search bar, you'll probably find a question or two about how to effectively shut down the editor. I like this post by Chris Sunami: https://writing.stackexchange.com/a/30983/41082

Answer (score 0):

You already know how to write stories.
You've been listening to them your whole life, and maybe telling a few.
Simply sit and start writing your stories.
Then rewrite your stories to make them better.
Then keep writing and rewriting your stories.

Comment: Trust your intuition: https://www.cnbc.com/2018/05/23/how-to-trust-your-intuition-like-apple-co-founder-steve-jobs.html